# How can I know the type of error and response code from IOWebSocketChannel

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

I am trying to know if the connection error is `Connection to 'some URL' was not upgraded to websocket`. Also identify response code. The server is emitting `401`.

I need this to know if I need to refresh the token and then reconnect.

```dart
final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(Url)
final sub = channel.stream.listen((data){
                                        //process data
                                     },
                                    onError: (error){
                                        //confirm this error failing to upgrade and
                                        // response code is 401

                                        // then refresh token and reconnect
                                     })
```

Answer (score 0):

To know the error type

```dart
print('error type is ${error.runtimeType}');
```

then you can handle it

```dart
if(error is errorType)
{
...
}
```